# Another example

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

Let $n \geq 2$.

I want to know an example of nonempty open set $O \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that :

There exists $C, \delta >0$ such that $|\{x \in O \mid \operatorname{dist}(x, \mathbb{R} \setminus O) < \varepsilon\}| \leq C {\varepsilon}^n$ for all $0<\varepsilon < \delta$,

where $|\cdot|$ indicates the lebesgue measure.

I know the case $O=\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m\}$. Does there exist another example?

Comment: Any $O$ with a non-weird compact boundary? -  In other words: Do you have a *counterexample* where any such distance-set is of finite volume and yet $C,\delta$ do not exist?

Comment: For example, $O$ is an open ball.